# Where does Atom store its recently opened files list?

Tags: atom-editor, recent-file-list

I'm using Atom 1.0.15. On startup, Atom tries to open a file on a MTP device every time, which is very annoying. Even after closing the tab referring to the file on the MTP device, Atom will try to reopen it on next startup.

A fix would probably be to clear the recently opened files list, but I can't find it. Where is it located?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick and inelegant way is to just clean your `~/.atom/storage` directory (`%HOMEPATH%\.atom\storage`).

This should 'reset' Atom to a project-less state.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I found out that the little bugger resided in `~/.atom/storage/applications.json`. Removing that file solved my problem.

Comment: This does not seem to be true anymore, because I deleted my whole .atom directory and it still knows all open files.

Comment: @BlaM Did you ever figure out how to do this? I "rm -rf ~/.atom", but when I open up a directory, and it still tries to open all it's open files.

Answer (score 1):

According to this site: [1](https://mpl.co/t/where-does-atom-store-the-unsaved-files/3478085), it saved it in indexedDB. So if you want to clear it:

1. Press ctrl-shift-i
2. Find the Application tab where you may see the IndexedDB databases.
3. You may delete the Atom* ones.